# How to use CoreCursor class in UniversalApp WindowsPhone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have used the following code

Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new CoreCursor(CoreCursorType.Arrow, 1);

to get the cursor and it working fine in UniversalApp WinRT (Windows). But  it not working in UniversalApp WindowsPhone, When i using above line in UniversalApp WindowsPhone it gives the exception for "**The method or operation is not implemented**".

Can any one help me ho how to achieve this in UniversalApp WindowsPhone ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep. That's because there is, basically, no cursor on the phone.

```
#if WINDOWS_APP
    // Cursor Code
#else
    // Alternate Code
#endif
```

Best of luck